# Devextreme Scheduler maxAppointmentsPerCell Value Cant Be Set With Multiple View(day, week, month)

Tags: scheduler, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I m using devextreme scheduler in my Angular 4 project. I'm using month, week and day views. When I set `maxAppointmentsPerCell`'s value to a number like 2, it gives

> ERROR RangeError: Invalid time value error on view changes.

My code:

```
<dx-scheduler
#scheduler
[dataSource]="schedulerData"
[views]='["day", "week", "month"]'
currentView="month"
[currentDate]="currentDate"
[startDayHour]="0"
[endDayHour]="24"
[showAllDayPanel]="false"
[firstDayOfWeek]="1"
[focusStateEnabled]="true"
(onAppointmentRendered)="onAppointmentRendered($event)"
(onAppointmentClick)="onApponintmentClick($event)"
(onOptionChanged)="onOptionChanged($event)"
(onCellClick)="onCellClick($event)"
(onAppointmentUpdating)="onAppointmentUpdating($event)"
maxAppointmentsPerCell="2"
[height]="800">
<dxo-editing #editingOptions
    [allowAdding]="false"
    [allowUpdating]="true"
    [allowDeleting]="false"
    [allowResizing]="true"
    [allowDragging]="true"
></dxo-editing>
</dx-scheduler>
```

When I set `maxAppointmentsPerCell`'s value to 'unlimitied', it is not throwing an error. But when appointments are more than 5 a month view the text of appointments disappears. I need to set that value to at most 4 but I don't know how to handle that error. How can I solve that problem??

Comment: I nee help ....